# How to revoke privileges from a public user in db2?

Tags: db2, public, privileges

Hi am trying to revoke the privileges of public users to create tables in my sample database.

Iam inserting this statement:

```
db2 revoke createtab on sample from public
```

While running this, the Database issues a problem.

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents>db2 revoke Createtab on sample from public
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0204N  "ADMINISTRATOR.SAMPLE" is an undefined name.  SQLSTATE=42704
```

I have created the database and I am also logged in as administrator.

I don't know where my problem is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

[REVOKE](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-revoke-database-authorities) CREATETAB ON **DATABASE** FROM PUBLIC

That is, you must not use the database name instead of the **DATABASE** keyword.